# Menu xml and ExpandableListView orientation in navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navigationview, android-navigationview

I implement ExpandableListView but i have also items in menu xml, so how can i declare that this list view should be below of one of the item inside of my menu.xml? For example if i want expandablelistview below location item what should i do? Here is my code:

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item android:id="@+id/location" android:icon="@drawable/mylocation" android:title="@string/My_Location"  android:animateLayoutChanges="true"/>

    </group>

    <item android:title="@string/action_settings">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item android:id="@+id/profile" android:icon="@drawable/settings"
                    android:title="@string/Edit_Profile" android:animateLayoutChanges="true" />
                <item android:id="@+id/logout" android:icon="@drawable/logout"
                    android:title="@string/Log_Out"  android:animateLayoutChanges="true"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

And drawer_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        app:itemIconTint="#FFFFFF"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#000000">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_list_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/navList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

So my problem is that the ExpandableListView remain top and i dont want to use layout_marginTop because it depends on user screen. Is there any other way to accomplish this issue?